# QGIS can not read float from SQL view

Tags: qgis, sql-view, floating-point, decimal-points

Geometry points from the SQL view `view_monitoring` with columns from table `table_campaign`, `table_instrument` etc. are shown in a QGIS-project. It works fine as long as no column of type `float` is involved. However, if a column of type `float` (e.g. `measurement` in `table_campaign`) is involved, the QGIS-project runs into a hang-up during the opening process (no error message, blue circle remains spinning). A work-around is to copy the content of the column `measurement` into a new column of type `decimal` (e.g. `measurement_dec`) and to use `measurement_dec` instead of `measurement` to build the view. The loss of preciseness due to this conversion is significant. Is there a known approach how to deal with columns of type `float` in order to make them usable for QGIS?

Technical data:

- Server where SQL database is stored:

  - Operating system: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
  - SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) SQL Server, version 14.0.2027.2
  - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: version 15.0.18206.0
- Client where QGIS runs:

  - Operating System: Windows 11 Pro, 21H2
  - QGIS version: 3.22.10-Białowieża / 3.28.1-Firenze

Comment: Seems to convert it in `REAL` works : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50865#issuecomment-1321868181

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in one of the latest cumulative updates (most likely KB5019959 ) for Windows/MS SQL Server driver.

This QGIS issue has more details: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50865