# QGIS has started putting all features into one row in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, sql-server

This is a bit of an odd one. We host our data in an Microsoft SQL Server database, and until a couple of weeks ago this was working fine. We've got about 17000 rows in it, all with a geometry.

When I got back from annual leave, I've found that this still works perfectly, until you go to the Attribute Table in QGIS. When you go there, everything is "summed up" into one row.

You can still filter the data using the Definition Query, query the data using the Identify tool, and even style it based on various criteria (even the primary key). I've also checked the primary key to ensure there are no duplicates, and that it is listed as a primary key.

One thing - this layer is a "view" of the main layer. For some reason we could never get the main layer itself to work properly with QGIS, so had to use a view which would simply select all the data from the main layer. It seems this issue is happening when we look at views, and not the layer itself.

As an aside, this is happening in various versions of QGIS (2.18, 3.4, 3.16, 3.22).

Comment: The database is SQL Server, yes? There have been multiple posts on this topic recently. Probably a driver patch thing.

Comment: Probably solving the issue with the main layer would be a good idea.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445719/qgis-can-not-read-float-from-sql-view

Comment: @Vince great find, thanks. I cast my floats out as decimals in the view (rather than reals, don't know why, but reals should work too) and that worked great. We're looking into which update caused this and trying to roll back. For those who haven't seen it yet, discussion is at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50865