# Azure SQL database tables are suddenly extremely slow to respond in QGIS to a click with the identify features tool

Tags: qgis, sql, identify, azure

I have been using QGIS 3.10 for several years to access an Azure SQL database spatial table with 49 fields (one of them a geometry field), and have been able to view the spatial information, and use the identify features tool to select one or more features.  Sometime last week (around 16 November 2022) this stopped working, with QGIS appearing to freeze.  I later discovered QGIS wasn't freezing completely, it just took something like 15 minutes for the results to appear.

- It's not slow with a new table with just 2 columns (primary key and geometry field)
- It's not slow with a copy of the original table with just the primary key and geometry columns and all 3600 rows
- It's not slow with a copy of the original table with all rows and the first 8 columns
- If I go above 8 columns (any 8 columns including the PK and geometry columns) QGIS takes 15 minutes or so to respond to a click with the identify features tool.
  I'm using QGIS 3.10 because I also use Intramaps Roam, which requires that version of QGIS.

I need the 49 columns of data.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does anyone know what query is actually run by the identify features tool so I can try running it in SSMS?

Comment: Probably related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445866/qgis-has-started-putting-all-features-into-one-row-in-attribute-table

Comment: Thanks @vince, that link and associated links look really useful, and an update to Microsoft's SQL Server Driver makes sense why the problem just appeared with no changes from our end.

Comment: The table involved does have 4 float columns, and it is float columns that the sql server driver seems now to be having problems with.  I tried using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server instead and that doesn't generate the same problem.  An alternative might be to try changing the float columns to Decimal as the precision in these fields is not critical, although I'm not sure what the implications are for other programming that relies on this table

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @vince comment I confirmed that my problem was caused by the recent windows updates to sqlsrv.dll choking on floats.

I tried in QGIS to convert the GIS project to use ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, but that didn't connect, whereas ODBC Driver 17 did, and I deleted the tables with floats from the project and recreated the layers using the ODBC 17 driver.  This worked fine in QGIS, but I am using Intramaps Roam for field data entry, which relies on the QGIS project file, and it started spitting errors.

So instead I have just converted the float columns in the various databases to decimals with the relevant precision.  Seems to be working fine, with no downstream programming issues so far.